# Filemaker PHP foreign key

Tags: php, filemaker

I have been able to successfully create records on a table that does not have foreign keys but keep running into the error "Field cannot be modified" when trying to set the foreign key on a table that has a foreign key to the first table. What is the correct way to set the foreign key on a table via PHP API?

```
$data = array(
  "_fk_LeadID"  => '24',
  "Date"    => "12/12/2016",
  "Result"  => "Still Investigating",
  "Sales_Rep" => "Joe",
  "Time"    => "9:00PM"
);

$rec = $fm->createRecord('Appointments', $data);
$result = $rec->commit();

if (FileMaker::isError($result)) { 
    echo "<p>Error: " . $result->getMessage() . "</p>"; 
    exit; 
}
```

I was looking through the PHP documentation and it mentioned portals but I didn't have one setup on these tables so wasn't able to use them. What is the correct way to set the foreign key on a table?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and the problem is not really PHP related. FileMaker PHP does not have any special functions for creating foreign keys, or even primary keys.So the issue is on FileMaker Server side.

You have an error that one of the fields is not modifiable. Most probably it is a calculation field (column populated by a trigger). I would try to set the fields manually in FileMaker and see if it gives you the same error (I suspect it would).

If you can't use FileMaker, create a record with _fk_LeadID only and see if there is an error, then start adding one field at the time. The field which throws an error is probably a calculation. E.g. Date and Time could be auto populated date and time of the record creation.

Comment: The error seems to be caused by the option "Prohibit Modification of value during data entry.", is there a way to create a record with this setting on?

Comment: You can turn it off, but most probably it is there for a reason. Try not to set this column in your code. Most probably it will be populated with the correct value.